# Threading and queue experiment

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm just beginning to get the idea of queue and threading.

I would welcome input on this exercise script:

```
from threading import Thread as T
from Queue import Queue as Q
from random import randint as R
import time

'''
Silly script exploring simple use of threadding.Thread and Queue.Queue
'''

q = Q()

now = time.time()

def one_up(queue):
        while time.time() - now <= 20:
                other_num = queue.get()
                big_num = 5*other_num
                print("       {}!?!?".format(other_num))
                queue.put(big_num)
                print("Oh yea, well I put {} in the queue!".format(big_num))
                time.sleep(1)
        print("{} is a BIG number, man. Wow. Look. We made a pyramid.".format(big_num))

a_num = R(1,10)
q.put(a_num)
print("I put {} in the queue.".format(a_num))
t = T(target=one_up, args=(q,))
t.start()
```

Which outputs something along the lines of:

> ```
>     I put 5 in the queue.
>        5!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 25 in the queue!
>        25!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 125 in the queue!
>        125!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 625 in the queue!
>        625!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 3125 in the queue!
>        3125!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 15625 in the queue!
>        15625!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 78125 in the queue!
>        78125!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 390625 in the queue!
>        390625!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 1953125 in the queue!
>        1953125!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 9765625 in the queue!
>        9765625!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 48828125 in the queue!
>        48828125!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 244140625 in the queue!
>        244140625!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 1220703125 in the queue!
>        1220703125!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 6103515625 in the queue!
>        6103515625!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 30517578125 in the queue!
>        30517578125!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 152587890625 in the queue!
>        152587890625!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 762939453125 in the queue!
>        762939453125!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 3814697265625 in the queue!
>        3814697265625!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 19073486328125 in the queue!
>        19073486328125!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 95367431640625 in the queue!
>        95367431640625!?!?
> Oh yea, well I put 476837158203125 in the queue!
> 476837158203125 is a BIG number, man. Wow. Look. We made a pyramid.
> ```

Comment: i can already see that the function should be documented. `'retrieve number from queue and replace it with number*5'` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single-letter variable names are usually a bad practice, with few exceptions (loop counters, caught exception objects). Importing modules with single-letter names is very silly indeed. So don't do this:

> ```
> from threading import Thread as T
> from Queue import Queue as Q
> from random import randint as R
> ```

Just stick to good old-fashioned:

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
from random import randint
```

This is not a very interesting experiment with threading and a Queue. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), it's quite basic but much more interesting, and really using threading and a Queue.

Comment: The original title actually contained the word newbie, but was edited by admins. Sorry if I got your hopes up that it might be interesting.

Comment: I hope I didn't offend you. I meant "interesting" not as "this is no fun for me get lost" but as "there's not a lot to review in this piece, but look, there's a cool doc about this, check it out you'll like it" ;-)

Comment: I think my ego did some into play a little bit. I have read through http://pymotw.com/2/Queue a few times, which offers a slightly more fleshed out version of the example in the Python docs. Learning it has felt like a slow process (pun intended).